# Thousand Separator with comma in columnGridView when the user is typing

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, number-formatting

I am gonna to separate numbers with comma,
What I am seeking is exactly like this

[Comma Separator in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675065/as-the-user-types-separate-numbers-with-commas-and-format-it-into-currency-in)

but the solution in that question did not work for me as I am doing this in column in gridview instead of textbox.

What I have done till now (part of the class for columns in a gridview):

```
public override string Text
{
    get { }
    set { base.Text = GetFormattedText(value); }
}

protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    Text = GetFormattedText(Text);
}

protected virtual string GetFormattedText(string text)
{
    string strText = text.Replace(",", "");
    decimal decValue = System.Convert.ToDecimal(strText);
    strText = decValue.ToString("#,##0");
    return strText;
}
```

So what happen with this piece of code:

**when I am typing 12345 in column it becomes ---> 51,234**

Pleae if my sayings are not clear tell me and I will explain it more

Comment: Try adding `base.SelectionStart = base.Text.Length;` in the `Text` setter after `base.Text=GetFormattedText(value);`

Comment: Why are you using your method in the setter of the property and in the override of the event method?

Comment: @juharr yes, the code is a bit strange, as first of all it won't even compile...maybe if OP post real code we could help.

Comment: @sariiia Glad it helped. I was not sure that was the problem but i guessed it was. I've added it as an answer :)

Comment: @juharr thank you pal for your answer, I just wanted to show that it is part of a big class implemented for column for gridview, and so all my columns behave as the functions in this class,(I could write that simply in this forum but I thought it may help that helper know that I have a class filled with functions for columns), again thank you man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you change the textbox text, the caret goes to the first position of the `TextBox`. So after setting the `TextBox` text with the formatted text, you must add this line to go to the end:

```
base.SelectionStart = base.Text.Length;
```

Comment: I have another problem related to this, I appreciate it if you could have a glance on my question, it is somehow strange, or probably my knowledge is little so it seems to me odd,    when I want to fill the datagridview, for example my datagridview has 3 column, name, count, fee, when I just straitforwardly go to fee column it works like a charm, I mean seperate digits when I am typing correctly, but when I firstly go to count column and then fee, it does not work, (I should say that in the second case it just call the get of my property) what should I do , thx pal

Comment: I explained it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115117/thousand-seperator-does-not-work-correctly-in-data-gridview     really thanks for your help