# Thousand seperator does not work correctly in data gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, digit-separator

please let me explain it clearly, if there is misconception please let me know,

firstly you suppose I have a grid with three column:

```
ItemName Count Fee
```

my code works perfectly when I click on `ItemName` and the go to fee column,
 mean in this case when I type 12345 it becomes 12,345 actually when I am typing.

but when I go to count column and then fee column it does not work 
for example when I am typing 12345 it does not put comma.

my code:

```
Public Override  string Text
{
    get
    {
        return base.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        base.Text=GetFormattedText(value);
    }
}


protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    Text= GetFormattedText(Text);
}

Protected virtual string GetFormattedText(string Text)
{
    string strText= text.Replace(",","");
    decimal  decValue=System.Convert.ToDecimal(strText);

    strText= decValue.Tostring("#,##0");
    Return strText;
}
```

**More explanation**
I am sure something is wrong with the GET of my property, because in this case, I mean when I go firstly to count column and then fee column it just calls get and doesn't go to `OnTextChanged`,

I know my question seems stupid because of my little knowledge but I really appreciate it if you could share some ideas

Comment: Showing a screenshot would help *a lot*, its hard to understand - seems only the Fee column is using the GetFormattedText code you need to figure out why Count isn't... How have you bound the grid columns, using a BindingSource control?

Comment: @JeremyThompson actually it calls this methods for every single cell, it is part of a large class for managing grid I couldnt load all of my code, just the piece of code that needed

Comment: You can just set `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0"` for the column in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @Fabio many thx fabio, but I am gonna to put comma when the user is typing not after moving to another cell, is this can do that also? if yes in which method I should put it?

Comment: @Fabio sadly it does not work in my case, I wanna to put comma when the user is typing not after type and leaving the cell, thax for your comment