# Firing The DataGridView CellValueChanged Event Immediately for doing thousand separator

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-handling, digit-separator

I kindly ask you patiently read my story for solving a seemingly simple problem,

my main purpose is to do thousand separator in datagridview,
It means when I am typing 12345 it becomes 12,345
the difference with other task is to do this when the user is typing not when he or she leave the cell,

I couldnt find any method in datagridview events that be fired whenever I add a digit in cell, for example if the purpose is to write 12345 in feeColumn it has to be fired five times,

After many research I came across with this code to do, but it has some problems:

```
myGrid:

ItemName  Quantity  FeeColumn


Private void grdTrading_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    If (grdTrading.IsCurrentCellDirty )
    {
        grdTrading.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)

    }
}

Private void grdTrading_CellValueChanged(object sender , System.Windows.FormsDataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   grdTrading.Columns[ColumnFee.Name].DefaultCellStyle.Format=(Decimal.Parse(grdTrading.Rows[0].Cells[ColumnFee.Name].Value.Tostring())).Tostring("#,##0")
}
```

**Now What is wrong?**

1. When it firstly goes to `grdTrading_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` and do commitedit it no longer allow to put any data in cell and remove the data while the user change its cell
2. now you suppose there is data, it successfully be run, and even run `cellValueChanged` once I add any digit to the fee column, 
   I mean 1 then 12 then 123 then 1234 then 12345
   but still there is no comma in my grid when I am typing,

I am really fed up with this problem, any help or any other solution is welcome to me  pal,

Comment: You appear to be setting the column's style format to the actual value of the cell, i.e. `column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "123,456"`.

Comment: If you want to apply thousand separator automatically while typing, first try it with a normal `TextBox`. Then if you succeed, handle `EditingControlShowing` event of `DataGridView` and get the `TextBox` which is showing as editing control and apply the logic to it.

Comment: @stuartd Thx for your comment, yes I am doing like this, and now I got what a stupid job I did, may I ask you to share your idea with me?

Comment: @RezaAghaei thx reza for your comment, it seems you are from Iran too, you mean I can do this with EditingControlShowing?  and may I ask you to share your code with me as I once did like this with another approach but It want successful again :( thx man for your help

Comment: I've never done it, but I'm sure if there is a way to add thousand separator while typing, you should first try to implement it using a normal `TextBox`. When you type in a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` in fact you are typing in a `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` which is derived from a `TextBox`. So you should first try to implement the logic (independent from a `DataGridView`) using a `TextBox` and if you succeed, then apply the logic to the editing control by handling `EditingControlShowing`. So start with a `TextBox`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei again thax reze for sharing your idea, I did once like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146236/thousand-comma-separator-in-gridview-when-typing-in-winforms?noredirect=1#comment69495371_41146236 that seems like your approach  but it has the problem in the aboved link

Comment: @sariiia Were you able to try the solution I posted? And is your question still unresolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Reza Aghaei has rightly pointed out, the idea here is to handle the `DataGridView.EditingControlShowing` event.  His advice to practice on the `TextBox` control is spot on, and I see you've generally the idea from your link in comments. You just need to hook it all up now:

```
this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += this.DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        tb.TextChanged -= Tb_TextChanged;
        tb.TextChanged += Tb_TextChanged;
    }
}
```

Now you can handle the `TextBox.TextChanged` event similarly to what you tried [in your other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41115117/3773066) Below I've shown my implementation, with some tweaks to the position of the selection cursor *more relative to its previous position*.

```
private void Tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    ulong value;
    string text = tb.Text.Replace(",", "");
    string old = tb.Text;

    if (ulong.TryParse(text, out value))
    {
        int start = tb.SelectionStart;
        tb.Text = string.Format("{0:n0}", value);
        tb.SelectionStart = Math.Max(0, start + tb.Text.Length - old.Length);

        if (tb.SelectionStart > 0 && tb.Text[tb.SelectionStart - 1] == ',')
        {
            tb.SelectionStart--;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

Sidenote: If this annoys your users (entirely plausible as this is not normal expected behavior - changing user input during a live edit), it's easy enough to revert to:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    ulong value;

    if (ulong.TryParse(e.Value?.ToString(), out value))
    {
        e.Value = string.Format("{0:n0}", value);
    }
}
```