# thousand comma separator in gridview when typing in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, digit-separator

I hope someone can help me, 
I need something like this : for example I type 12345 in fee column in gridview it becomes 12,345
not after the user left the column, but when she is typing,

you should suppose this is my grid

```
ItemNameColumn  QuantityColumn  FeeColumn
```

I wrote my solution here
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978277/thousand-separator-with-comma-in-columngridview-when-the-user-is-typing)

it workd perfectly provided that the user firstly click on the fee column,
In case I fill the quantity column which is before the Fee column it does not work anymore,

Now I am not strict on the approach I used before, any method that help me to solve this problem is welcome to me,

please kindly have a glance and let me know if there is any misconception,

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115117/thousand-seperator-does-not-work-correctly-in-data-gridview)

Comment: @stuartd thanks it was written by my college with my user as the password is saved in the browser, sorry for duplication, but it seems there was nt a good answer for that question, I am wondering if this question is hard really?

Comment: @stuartd apart from that I am not inline with his point of view for the reason of the problem,